# how to convert from json to angular class

Tags: json, converters, angular6

I have a class named book in angular

```
export class Book
{
  name: String;
  auther: String;
  series: String;

  price: Number;
  publishDate: Date;
  ISBN: Number;
  promise: String;


  active: boolean;
}
```

and using httpClient I get the book's data from the server (in json format) like so

```
this.http.get(this.booksUrl)
  .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

I want to convert from json to the book class, is there a package for that?
if how can I extract the data from the json object

UPDATE:
this is the json data I get

```
ISBN:"req.body.ISBN"
author:"req.body.author"
created_at:"2018-08-06T11:53:07.532Z"
name:"a"
photo:""
publishDate:"2018-08-06T11:53:07.532Z"
sellDate:"2018-08-06T11:53:07.532Z"
seller:"req.body.seller"
seriesName:"4"
summary:"req.body.summary"
updated_at:"2018-08-06T11:53:17.629Z"
__v:0
_id:"5b6836aa5d6e0a2c481fbd04"
```

Comment: added an example with the published date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this code in the end

```
getBookList() {
    return this.http.get<Book[]>(this.bookUrl + '/list')
        .subscribe(bookRes => this.books = bookRes);
  }
```

since the I got the respond in json this cast was able to cast any object of the same name from json to Book.
for example I have an author variable in book so as long it's the same name in the json document and in the book class it will be able to cast it, but if in my class i'll call this variable "BooksAuthor" ,since it's a diffrent name than the json document I won't be able to cast it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple constructor that receives an Object like this:

```
export class Book
{
  name: String;
  auther: String;
  series: String;

  price: Number;
  publishDate: Date;
  ISBN: Number;
  promise: String;


  active: boolean;

  constructor(obj: any) {
    this.name = obj.name;
    this.auther = obj.auther;
    this.publishDate = new Date(obj.publishDate);
  }
}
```

Then update you request like this:

```
this.http.get(this.booksUrl)
  .subscribe(res => new Book(res));
```

Obviously I think you would associate new created Book with an instance, something like:

```
book: Book;

this.http.get(this.booksUrl)
      .subscribe(res => {
           this.book = new Book(res)
});
```

Comment: I also have dates variable ,how do I convert them?

Comment: it depends on how you receive them. post a received json please

Comment: it didn't work for me
Object doesn't have "name" property or "author" property but I found another way

Comment: i edited answer. however share your solution adding an answer to your post